# Returning a pointer from a user defined function in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am completing an assignment that is helping me understand the use of pointers. I feel like I have a good grasp except when it comes to returning the pointer from a function. Here is the code I'm having trouble with:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <time.h>

double *ptr;
double * userallocate(double numbers)
{
    if (numbers < 1000000)
    {
        ptr = malloc(sizeof(double)*numbers); 
        return ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You have allocated too many numbers... SHAME\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}

double * gendata(double *ptr, double numbers)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<numbers;i++)
        ptr[i] = rand()/RAND_MAX;
    return ptr;
}

void average(double numbers)
{
    int i;
    double sum, average;
    for (i=0;i<numbers;i++)
        sum+=ptr[i];
    average = sum/numbers;
    printf("%f,",sum);
    printf("We have averaged %d random numbers for you.\n The average is %f",(int) numbers,average);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double num;
    if (argc !=2)
    {
        printf("Not enough arguements... SHAME\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    num = atof(argv[1]);

    userallocate(num);
    gendata(ptr,num);
    average(num);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The first function `userallocate()` is meant to create a buffer that contains space for double precision with the size determined by the command line argument. My code compiles but when I try to put random numbers into the buffer and average them I get `0.0000`. I think there is a problem with the way I am returning the pointer in `userallocate()` and passing it to the other functions. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Returning and passing your pointer works, but uses a global variable. This is considered bad practice. Make it a local variable instead - that is, move the `double *ptr;` from line 5 in your code inside the `main` function, that is, together with `double num;`

Comment: Although @jxh pointed out the averaging problem your comment is more what I'm struggling to understand. When I place `double *ptr` inside main then I get a compiling error `error: ‘ptr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(double)*numbers);`as well as the other functions 
    ^

Comment: Oh right, you should have it in `userallocate` too. And also in `average` (as a parameter).

Comment: BTW also (unrelated): `double sum` should be `double sum = 0`

Comment: So in essence: local variables need to be defined for each function they are used in? Even when I'm returning the local variable from `userallocate()` to main? I guess in my head I thought once its returned to main it would magically jump around to the other functions :-)

Comment: It's the global variables that "magically" jump around. People prefer to define explicitly which variables go to functions, and which are returned to `main` - to make the flow of information more intuitive.

Comment: The primary disadvantage of  `average` and `userallocate` as implemented is that they can only be used for the global `ptr`. If you wanted to allocate and take the average of a different array in the same program, you would have to write different functions that accessed a different global variable. But, the nicer alternative is to change your functions to use a function parameter, so that the function can be reused for different arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see `0.0000` has nothing to do with pointers.

`rand()` returns an `int`, and `RAND_MAX`, also an `int`, will most likely be greater than the value returned by `rand()`, so most of the time the result of the integer division is 0.

If you want floating point results, you will need to have one of the arguments to the division be a floating point type.

```
        ptr[i] = rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
```